# How print landscape multible pages in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, internet-explorer-11

How print multiple pages in landscape view for IE?
My content with charts and tables, I tried:

```
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
```

In Chrome i use @page and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease use -ms-transform for IE11.
This code solved my problem:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(x, 0) scale(x),
transform-origin: 0 0,
```